# How to receive bpdu traffic using raw socket in Linux C

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming, raw-sockets

How to get packets using `recvfrom()`? And how to know is it bdpu traffic?
I read somesource but didn't find listen ethernet traffic.

```
int data_size, addr_size;
char reply[6000];
struct sockaddr_in addr;

addr_size = sizeof addr;
datasize = recvfrom(sock, reply, 6000, 0, &addr, &addr_size);

if(data_size<0)
{
    printf("nothing recv");
}
printf("%x",reply);
```

Output:

```
651a7ec0
```

What is this? I don't know.

Comment: The number you printed is the address of the `reply` array, not the content. Also if the return value of `recvfrom` is `-1`, it means error, you should check `errno` for it.

Comment: So how to get content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the *reply* variable is a pointer to a 6000 byte array. When recvfrom returns, if fills this array with *datasize* bytes. To see the content, iterate over *reply* from index 0, until *datasize*:

```
for(i=0;i<datasize;i++)
{
    printf("%02x ",reply[i]);
}
```

I suggest declaring *reply* as `unsinged char reply[6000]`.